# ajax call hanging in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make ajax calls in sequence and then apply handlebars for appending them to main html file. but my below code is getting hung in its first request only. when i try this url manually it return html. but not when i am trying through. Am i making any logical mistake over here.

```
var i = 0;
var flagArray = new Array(data.length);
while (i < data.length) {
    if (flagArray[i] == 'done') {
        i++;
        console.log(i);
    }
    if (flagArray[i] != 'fired') {
        flagArray[i] = 'fired';
        $.get('commonCore/templates/' + data[i].templateHtml, function (html) {
            console.log(data[count].classSelect, i);
            var filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(html);
            replaceFilterTemplate(filterTemplate, data[i].classSelect);
            flagArray[i] = 'done';
        });
    }
}
```

data is json:

```
[
    {
        "templateHtml": "dcdcsFilterOptions.html",
        "classSelect": "dcdcsOptions"
    },
    {
        "templateHtml": "dashBoardLeftInsight.html",
        "classSelect": "leftpanel"
    },
    {
        "templateHtml": "advanceFilterOptions.html",
        "classSelect": "advancedOptions"
    },
    {
        "templateHtml": "reportFilterOptions.html",
        "classSelect": "reportdashboard"
    }
]
```

in chrome network shows pending status for the first request forever and hence everything is hanging. but manuall try returns data.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. The Ajax callback can never be executed because the loop doesn't terminate. So, `flagArray[i]` cannot be set to `'done'` and `i` doesn't get increased. Is there a specific reason why you want to execute the Ajax calls in sequence? Why not run them in parallel?

Comment: yes sir because this will create my page and there is dependency on first to next. next will only get appended on first's bottom id which is their in html... so

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sequential requests try something like

```
function request(array) {
    if (!array || !a.length) {
        return
    }
    var item = array.shift();
    $.get('commonCore/templates/' + item.templateHtml, function (html) {
        var filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(html);
        replaceFilterTemplate(filterTemplate, item.classSelect);
        request(array)
    });
}
request(data)
```

The problem with your code till the entire array of requests are processed you are blocking the browser thread because of the while loop

Comment: Did you forget to call `request` inside the callback?

Comment: actually it need to be blocked... because this will first create the page on which rest of the code will operate.

Comment: @user3115998 that is a very bad idea... a better solution will be to block the ui using a panel like loading message

Answer (score 0):

You are facing session hang issue due to simultaneous session blocking ajax calls and those are locking the session files.

Please use the session_write_close() function before you return the response to resolve the issue as described here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

This will also improve the performance while making simultaneous ajax calls as shown in this demo https://demo.ma.ttias.be/demo-php-blocking-sessions/.

Here is more detail on this. https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/